# Make a copy of 2 spreadsheets. Connect them and send an email to the collaborators by using Google App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to automate the process of my daily interaction with Google Spreadsheet.

Actually, I have 2 well-crafted spreadsheets for tracking portfolios. One sheet is used for Input purpose and another is for Display purpose only. These both sheets are connected through Importance function (for transferring data from Input to Display sheet).

I usually distribute my spreadsheet to around 20 people per week so here I have to create a copy and then change their Importrange function sheetId and then email them all with their individual spreadsheet links.

So I need to make an automated workflow which will whenever XYZ trigger fired (like inserting an email in a spreadsheet).

Here is the complete workflow, I'm trying to automate:

- (Manual trigger) Insert an email in spreadsheet ABC.
- (Automate) Create a copy of Spreadsheet display & Spreadsheet Input.
- (Automate) Autolink these both sheets by changing the sheet ID in the Import range function in Spreadsheet XYZ. (Hint: Get sheetID from Spreadsheet PRQ and send it to spreadsheet PQR)
- (Automate) Send an email to the applicants (with Display Spreadsheet ID).

I tried many times to automate this process through get.sheetid,sendEmail,copyTo etc but every time I failed.

What should be the bug-free process to regulate the process?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and know why its marked to be closed.